# ImportError: No module named 'thinc.about'

Tags: windows, python-3.x, spacy

I am trying to install spacy for windows, python 3.x.
I ran the following commands:-

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

"python -m spacy download en" gives the error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 133, in _get_module_details
return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
__import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .download import download
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 10, in <module>
from .link import link
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\link.py", line 7, in <module>
from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .about import *
ImportError: No module named 'thinc.about'
```

and the same error when I try to import spacy thereafter. What should I do to successfully install spacy?

Comment: I have also tried to install thinc with:-
pip install thinc==6.8.1 and conda install thinc==6.8.1
pip throws errror and conda can't find the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#spacy) from where I downloaded all of the required whls one by one to install spacy.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling wheel rather than downloading ready one might be helpful as well:

```
python -m pip install thinc --no-binary=:all:
```

or

```
pip install thinc --no-binary=:all:
```

Don't forget to add --force option if you already have the package.

More information about --no-binary option:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary